# BTreeSet contains value (with custom Ord implementation) and falsely returns true for `contains`

Tags: rust, traits

I have a `BTreeSet` that stores values of type:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: usize,
    pub thing_to_compare: usize,
}

impl Ord for PriorityEntry {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        // Sort in reverse order
        other.thing_to_compare.cmp(&self.thing_to_compare)
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for PriorityEntry {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}

impl PartialEq for PriorityEntry {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.a == other.a && self.thing_to_compare == other.thing_to_compare
    }
}
```

The idea is that the structs in the `BTreeSet` should be sorted by `thing_to_compare` and the `a` field is just additional information.

I'm noticing that if I have a `BTreeSet` with

```
{ a: 0, thing_to_compare: 0 }
```

then `contains` will return `true` for

```
{ a: 1, thing_to_compare: 0 }
```

I'm guessing that it returns `true` because `cmp` will return `Ordering::Equal` for the two values since they have the same `thing_to_compare`. What I'm confused about is why the `BTreeSet` doesn't use the auto-generated `Eq` trait or `PartialEq` trait to check if the value exists inside of itself.

Afterall, I assume that the `Ord` trait should only be relevant to sorting and not whether two values are the same.

Answer (score 6):

The [docs for `Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#how-can-i-implement-ord) say:

> Implementations of `PartialEq`, `PartialOrd`, and `Ord` *must* agree with
> each other. It's easy to accidentally make them disagree by deriving some
> of the traits and manually implementing others.

In other words, you need to ensure that `(a == b) == (a.cmp(b) == Ordering::Equal)` because other code (e.g. `BTreeSet`) is allowed to assume that this property holds; otherwise you can get incorrect (but not unsafe) behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is that the structs in the `BTreeSet` should be sorted by `thing_to_compare`

Sorting is how btrees are internally organised, as with Hash/Eq for HashSets. This means that `thing_to_compare` is your BTreeSet's "identity" information, it's not just a surface-level display or iteration order.

> What I'm confused about is why the BTreeSet doesn't use the auto-generated Eq trait or PartialEq trait to check if the value exists inside of itself.

Because why would it? `Ord` is what it requires and what it uses to probe itself internally. If your `Ord` is broken then forget equality, the entire set will be internally inconsistent.